# How to make a QR code to automatically like a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, qr-code

How can I make a QR code, that when scanned - automatically likes a page, if it wasn't already liked, whether in a browser or the Facebook app?
I'm not talking about legal issues now, just technically, how is it possible?

Comment: Do you want a QR code for a specific page or for any page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API available to do this. Best you could do is have it open the page.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. It's just yesterday I scanned some code, it took me to some company's page and I saw that I automatically liked them. So I wanted to see how it works. So I created a QR code with a link to some other company's FB page, which I know for sure I never liked, and when I scanned that code - I see that page is liked. But when I check my account - I don't see that I liked that page. Something's really weird here...

Comment: do you remember that page you liked? I saw some apps those generate qr codes for automatic/semiautomatic facebook likes but they don't work

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Facebook page to create a Like Us button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
Create a button.
Click the button.
Copy the Like Us URL that the button takes you to.

Open bitly.com or another site that creates short URLs.
Paste the Like Us URL.
Copy the shortened URL that bitly generates.

Use an [online QR code generator](https://www.scan.me/qr-code-generator/) to create the image.

Paste the shortened URL you get from bitly to generate the QR image.

Comment: Works for me. Only drawback is that after the 'do you want to like this page' page is shown, it goes to a page with just a link to go back to FB developer page.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should find a QR code generator site like given by me(or you can write with java) after that go

1:[A free QR code generator site](http://qrcode.kaywa.com/)
Then

2: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and generate a like button. (it is at first, after click **Get Code**. In opened window click to URL and copy it to QR code site's url area than create your QR code for facebok like.

**Note: While generating a like button at facebook page inactive Send Button option. That is important for generating Url**

Comment: Well, it generated the button, I saw it in my browser after scanning the code, but it didn't do automatic liking. I guess it really is impossible. Still, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I like the generator with different social and link type on http://www.softwaresupply.de/services/qr-code-generator. Its ok, since you have many options, even though the size is very small.

Answer (score 0):

The free QR code generator I use for this task is: 
http://scan.me/qr-code-generator

It actually opens a button in their phone's browser for them to click like.  On Android, you have to choose open in browser though, so it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It actually opens a button in their phone browser in order to enable them to click 'like'. On Android, you have to choose open in the browser though, so it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a 3rd party server to host a page for you then you could point the QR code at that and embed redirects or ajax into javascript on load

Answer (score 0):

You should go to [enter link description here](https://app.qr-code-generator.com)
It's an online APP that enables you to create a QR Code with an automatic "iLike", as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you want to Generate Facebook Page QR code then you may follow these steps that mention at How To Generate/Create QR Code For Facebook Business Page - Ganvwale (https://ganvwale.com/how-to-create-qr-code-for-facebook-business-page/) here step-by-step guide given to create a QR code for Facebook Business/Brand page.